# Call a Perl script in AWK

Tags: perl, awk, ksh

I have a problem that I need to call a Perl script with parameters passing in and get the return value of the Perl script in an AWK `BEGIN` block. Just like below.

I have a Perl script util.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$res=`$exe_cmd`;
print $res;
```

Now in the AWK `BEGIN` block (ksh) I need to call the script and get the return value.

```
BEGIN { print "in awk, application type is " type;  
                    } \
            {call per script here;}
```

How do I call the Perl script with parameter and get the return value of `$res`?

```
res = util.pl a b c;
```

Comment: I really don't mean this to sound snarky, but is there some reason not just to make the whole script in Perl? Unless it is a large mature AWK script, I might suggest using Perl for the whole thing.

Comment: Quite so. Especially when your Perl script is shelling out to yet another process anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipe the script into `getline`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
         cmd = "util.pl a b c"; 
         cmd | getline res; 
         close(cmd);
         print "in awk, application type is " res
     }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of an AWK-script I use for extracting data from a `ldap` query. Perhaps you can find some inspiration from how I do the base64 decoding below...

```
    /^dn:/{
        if($0 ~ /^dn: /){
            split($0, a, "[:=,]")
            name=a[3]
        }
        else if($0 ~ /^dn::/){
            # Special handling needed since ldap apparently
            # uses base64 encoded strings for *some* users
            cmd = "/usr/bin/base64 -i -d <<< " $2 " 2>/dev/null"
            while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) { }
            close(cmd)
            split(result, a, "[:=,]")
            name=a[2]
        }
    }
```